# Convert session value into Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I store image into session in base64 format,
how can I convert it into byte[]

I want to do something like this:

```
Byte[] bytes =(Byte[]) Session["picimg"];
```

it's not working.

This is my code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream); 
String Data = Server.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
reader.Close();
 DateTime nm = DateTime.Now;
string date = nm.ToString("yyyymmddMMss");
        //used date for creating Unique image name

Session["capturedImageURL"] = Server.MapPath("Userimages/") + date + ".jpeg";

Session["Imagename"] = date + ".jpeg";
// We can use name of image where ever we required that why we are storing in Session

        drawimg(Data.Replace("imgBase64=data:image/png;base64,", String.Empty), Session["capturedImageURL"].ToString());

        // it is method 
        // passing base64 string and string filename to Draw Image.
 Session["picimg"] = (Data.Replace("imgBase64=data:image/png;base64,", String.Empty));

        Byte[] bytes =(Byte[]) Session["picimg"];
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"Userimages", bytes);
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to cache images into SessionState. Your server will run out of memory very quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [Convert.FromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) method to decode the base64 string into a byte array.

```
byte[] Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(DataInBase64);
```